# Month and year view of Bootstrap Datepicker 4 is not correct inside ASP:TreeView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

When I change Month or year then year and month view is displaying in line rather than in block and going outside to the container.
I am attaching my code and picture here. 
Thanks in advance.

```
TreeNode submission_date = new TreeNode();
                submission_date.Text = "<div class='input-group date qnbSimpleDatePicker'><input class=\"form-control readOnly\" id=\"TBsubmission_date\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + TBSubmitionDate + "\" title=\"Submission date and time\" required/><span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></span></div>";
                submission_date.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                Report.ChildNodes.Add(submission_date);
```

It displays inside the ASP:TrewView control because of some requirements. I am also using it in other forms where it is working correctly. Only problem is inside tree view.

```
$('.qnbSimpleDatePicker').datetimepicker({

    showClear: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    format: "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
});
```

[Image for Month and year list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5BKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself, The solution is to remove style attribute of parent td element of this datepicker.
By default asp:treeview renders elements in the form tables, each element has a separate table,tr,td. And for every td it giving styling like this style=white-space:nowrap; just remove it by jquery after rendering your tree.